# Google can't find my keyfilePath in my NextJS app?

Tags: next.js, google-api

I am trying to authenticate with `@google-cloud/local-auth` in a NextJS app. I am using the `authenticate` method, which takes 2 arguments, `keyfilePath` and `scopes`.

I can read the file from the `keyfilePath`, but when I pass it as an argument to google, I get the error `Error: Cannot find module` . Here is the code.

```
      const values = await readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH, "utf-8");
      console.log("values", values);
      const newClient = await authenticate({
        scopes: SCOPE,
        keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
      });
```

I can read the values from the CREDENTIALS_PATH. The file logs out as expected. When I use the same path in the `authenticate` function, I get `Error: Cannot find module` .

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include a [example]